# Can polymagnets be used to make a more efficient electric generator?

Tags: electromagnetism

I work for a very large industrial automation company. When polymagnets came out, I was very excited. I've thought of tons of uses for them.

http://www.polymagnet.com/polymagnets/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IANBoybVApQ

One of the uses I thought about was making more efficient power generators (and, obviously, motors). I ran this idea by a senior manager (been in the industry for a long time) at my office and he said that we've basically reached the peak efficiency of permanent magnet generators. This guy is pretty pessimistic about everything in general. He said that whether or not you used polymagnets, the only way to increase the efficiency was to get higher flux magnets, and we don't have anything better than NdFeB. He also said that eventually you get a problem where the back EMF becomes a problem.

My intuition tells me that if you can get higher magnetic attraction force close to the surface of a magnet such as a polymagnet, you should have a more intense field. And in my head, that should change things. I suppose if it was possible (and obviously extremely profitable), it would already have been done by now.

My question is, can you give me a better explanation than my pessimistic coworker as to why polymagnets aren't a game-changer when it comes to power generation? I have a degree in mechanical engineering, but all I do at work is use my minor in computer science to write software. So, while my engineering skills are a bit rusty you don't have to dumb it down too much for me.